# Upgrade MySQL ZIP, from 5.6 to 8 - not working

Tags: mysql, zip, upgrade, mysql-5.6, mysql-8.0

Currently In my windows 10 machine, I am using **MySQL 5.6** ***zip Archive*** version. and using HeidiSQL(zip file) as DB client.Everything working fine.

To start the server I am following these steps

1. cmd
2. <>/MySql\mysql-5.6.19-winx64\bin
3. start mysqld

Now I am trying to upgrade to latest MySQl 8 (and same zip file)
And following same above steps, but Not working.
can help me on this.

Comment: I were also expecting support of mysql 5.6 to 8.0 direct update. But now it's look like a two step migration :(

Answer (score 4):

In order to upgrade from version **5.6** to **MySQL 8**, first you need to upgrade to version **5.7** as that was a major release and you cannot skip a major release version.

From MySQL Docs:

- Upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 is supported. However, upgrade is only
  supported between General Availability (GA) releases. For MySQL 8.0,
  it is required that you upgrade from a MySQL 5.7 GA release (5.7.9 or
  higher). Upgrades from non-GA releases of MySQL 5.7 are not
  supported.
- Upgrading to the latest release is recommended before upgrading to
  the next version. For example, upgrade to the latest MySQL 5.7
  release before upgrading to MySQL 8.0.
- **Upgrade that skips versions is not supported. For example, upgrading
     directly from MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 is not supported.**

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html

Comment: Is it true that we can't upgrade from 5.6 to 8.0 directly?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details and link to the MySQL docs.